# How to restore data from SQL Server database in VS 2015 after detaching

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In Visual Studio Community 2015, in SQL Server Object Explorer I clicked `Detach` on database (by mistake).

After restart my solution I have that DB, app can use it but it hasn't any data.

What can I do to retrieve data?

Comment: re-attach the db?

Comment: Now DB looks like attached (I reopened solution only). After rightclick I see "Detach" option.